# SSIS Lookup: Want to use no matching records only

Tags: ssis

I tried to configure the lookup to only send no match output (Only want records that haven't been written to destination), but the same amount of records get written over and over. Is there something I am missing? I have the fields the lookup needs to match on, so if no match I want it to write to new location.

Specify how to handle rows with no matching entries is set to Redirect rows to no match output.

I would normally just use a query but where I am at the source and the destination are on two different servers.

Comment: Are you sending records that fail the lookup to to an OLE  DB destination and creating new records using the "Configure Error Output" option to redirect rows on failure? Have you tried using a Data Viewer to see what data is being sent this way? A screenshot of the Data Flow might help (i.e. Add it to your question)

Comment: Also, you might be comparing null values in destination table and blank values from your source.

Comment: Looks like I need to setup Lookup Match Output to a conditional split then look for nulls. Will try when I get into work. Thanks guys - your comments helped me rethink my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

With that Lookup configuration, you will have 2 green output paths available from the Lookup object.  One will be the Lookup Match Output and the other will be the Lookup No Match Output.

When connecting the Lookup to your downstream transformations, you need to carefully select which output path goes where. The one you probably want is the Lookup No Match Output.